# Pandas resampling data within two two columns

Tags: pandas, count, resampling

I have a dataframe with datetimes which I want to resample to 20 minutes and count for all groups 'name'  the number of unique values given in column 'trip'.

```
    name            Date         trip
0     4 2019-08-22 00:44:51      1
1     4 2019-08-22 00:45:40      1
2     4 2019-08-22 01:45:52      2
3     4 2019-08-22 01:44:51      2
4     4 2019-08-22 01:45:40      2
5     5 2019-08-22 01:45:52      3
6     5 2019-08-22 01:45:59      3
```

Desired output looks like:

```
Date                    Trip count
2019-08-22 00:40:00     1   
2019-08-22 01:00:00     0
2019-08-22 01:20:00     0
2019-08-22 01:40:00     2
2019-08-22 02:00:00     0
```

So the trip is 1 because there is only 1 trip (from name=4) between 00:40:00 and 01:00.
Trip is 2 because there are 2 trips (from name=4 and name=5) between 01:40:00 and 02:00.
Trip count is 0 else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `set_index` with `DataFrame.resample` and `nunique` of `trip`:

```
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
dfn = df.set_index('Date').resample('20T')['trip'].nunique().reset_index(name='Trip count')

                 Date  Trip count
0 2019-08-22 00:40:00           1
1 2019-08-22 01:00:00           0
2 2019-08-22 01:20:00           0
3 2019-08-22 01:40:00           2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Erfan, I like the solution. My date is now given from 2019-08-01 00:00:00 to 2019-08-31 00:40:00, do you know how I can get the mean values of the 'Trip count' during the day? So from 00:00:00 to 23:40:00 mean values every 20 minutes?

Comment: Happy I could help, Im not fan of the idea that people ask new questions as a comment underneath an existing question, but what you want is: `df.set_index('Date').resample('20T')['trip'].mean()`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I will make a new thread. Your last solution was not what I was looking for. I ll clarify in a new post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DataFrame.groupby('Date').resample('20T').trip.nunique()
```

Ref:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html